# Does anyone know how to reference other subifles in LaTex?

Tags: pdftex

So far what I have is this

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\item\href{\%202021-05-26-vqas-challenges\%20\%\%7D}{VQAs -- challenges and progress}
```

But it doesn't work. What I'm trying to do is I have a main file, and in that main file I want to encode a link that when the person viewing the pdf of that main file clicks on that link it will open a separate file. The files are meant to be downloaded together, so it just brings you from one to the other and you can go back and forth.

Comment: It will help if you can expand your code, so that it provides a "minimal working example" from `\documentclass` down to `\end{document}`. Do not use any packages that are inessential. One line of text suffices. In your specific case, maybe tow MWE that are supposed to link the way you want. Also tell us how you compile it (pdftex, lualatex, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your file name (in the href) is " 2021-05-26-vqas-challenges %}" (with a space at the front, and a `%}` at the end). The link automatically (on my copy) adds `.pdf`, so the file is  `2021-05-26-vqas-challenges %}.pdf`.

From a few tests with various combinations of spaces ( ), percent-signs (`%`), and close-braces (`}`), and having a local file, most of the links work.

What doesn't work (for me, at least), is having a percent in the filename like that. If your filename has `%}` as the last two characters (before the `.pdf`), you will need to encode the percent-sign properly, so, something like this:
`\href{\%202021-05-26-vqas-challenges\%20\%25\%7D}{VQAS -- Challenges and progress}`

Full document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%\maketitle %commented out, as it is not really relevant for the issue
% and produces the error `No \title given'

%\item %commented out, because it causes an error
\href{\%202021-05-26-vqas-challenges\%20\%25\%7D}{VQAs -- challenges and progress}
\end{document}
```

Otherwise, correct the filename (something like `\href{2021-05-26-vqas-challenges}{VQAS -- Challenges and progress}` and it should work.

Compiling this with `pdflatex` appears to work, and will open the other PDF file when clicked.

Other notes: as @rallg mentioned, a full minimal working example (or non-working, if that's the problem) really helps people who spend their time helping you. Start with `\documentclass` (with the actual documentclass you used), through to `\end{document}`.

In your example, I also get `! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.` (because of the `\item`) and `! LaTeX Error: No \title given` (because of `\maketitle`) as errors.